# Mysql query if statement, update error

Tags: mysql, sql

Good morning, I´m trying to move up and down nodes in traversal tree, but problem is, that if I have query for moving node up, it throws me an error in sql syntax, please, do you have any idea, where the problem is?

```
UPDATE categories 
SET lft = IF( lft >= 17 AND rgt <= 18, lft + 1, IF(lft >= 15 AND rgt <= 16, lft - 1)), 
    rgt = IF( lft >= 17 AND rgt <= 18, rgt + 1, IF(lft >= 15 AND rgt <= 16, rgt - 1))
WHERE (rgt <= 18 AND lft >= 15)
```

Thank you for your answers and solutions!

EDIT:
Thank you for your help, it works except one problem - second condition. It doesn´t do anything with right values:
parent rgt is still same and rgt of moved element is setted to 0. 
Where could be problems?
So problem solved. My faul. I was comparing edited values to so it was mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed third argument in inner IF()

Try this

```
   UPDATE categories 
    SET lft = IF( lft >= 17 AND rgt <= 18, lft + 1, IF(lft >= 15 AND rgt <= 16, lft - 1,0)), 
        rgt = IF( lft >= 17 AND rgt <= 18, rgt + 1, IF(lft >= 15 AND rgt <= 16, rgt - 1,0))
    WHERE (rgt <= 18 AND lft >= 15)
```

You can replace 0 with anything

Answer (score 2):

You are missing third argument in inner IF() function call, e.g

```
IF(lft >= 15 AND rgt <= 16, lft - 1)
                          ^        ^^^^
```

it should be:

```
IF(lft >= 15 AND rgt <= 16, lft - 1, else_stmt_expre) 
                                     ^^^^^ missing
```

Comment: @JanKožušník replace `else_stmt_expre` with 0